# Try with resources fails to compile with 'not a statement' errors

Tags: java, linux

I have bought a book today about "parallel and distributed applications in java" and its from 2014.

I run Kali Linux 64Bit and while compiling I get a bunch of errors like the following view example. all in all about 17 errors.

```
Server.java:7: '{' expected
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(27015)) {
           ^
Server.java:88: not a statement
        } catch(Exception e) {
Server.java:96: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
```

I got the example from the book, written in 2014 so i think there shouldn't be any errors but it wont work.

The try-catch blocks are ok as far as i can see and catch block with resource is explicit given in the example of the book.

As far as i know in Kali Linux is OpenJDK preinstalled and maybe that could be the error but I'm not sure. i hope its an adequate place for this type of question and someone could inspect that code for me.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(27015)) {

            while(true) {

                System.out.println("[info] Server in listen mode...");

                try {

                    TCPSocket tcpSocket = new TCPSocket(serverSocket.accept());
                    new Slave(tcpSocket);

                } catch(Exception e) {

                    //error handling

                }

            }

        } catch(Exception e) {

            // error handling

        }

    }

}

// Class Server Ende

class Slave extends Thread {

    private TCPSocket socket;

    public Slave(TCPSocket socket) {

        this.socket = socket;
        this.start();

    }

    public void run() {

        try(ServerSocket s = socket) {      

            while(true) {

                String request = s.receiveLine();

                if(request != null) {

                    try {

                        int secs = Integer.parseInt(request);
                        Thread.sleep(secs * 1000);

                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {

                        // error handling
                        System.out.println(e);

                    }

                    s.sendLine(request);

                } else {

                    break;

                }

            }

        } catch(Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);

        }

        System.out.println("[info] Connection closed");

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you targetting 1.6 bytecode, or using JDK 1.6?

Comment: yes: java version "1.6.0_34"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.6) (6b34-1.13.6-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: How about using a Java version which isn't 3 years old? Use at least Java 7 to use the try-with-resources statement.

Comment: Try with resources was introduced in 1.7

Comment: Don't know - shouldn't be too hard to get it even if it's not available through apt-get

Comment: ok i will accept your answer in 1 minute. thank you :D

Comment: I think that type of links is not welcome and also i will not follow. Just a guess!

Comment: @BrainWorx *"also i will not follow"* Kind of ironic, because it leads you to "let me google that for you" ... ;P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

```
Server.java:7: '{' expected
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(27015)) {
```

Indicates that java does not recognise that type of statement. Try with resources was introduced in java 1.7. I suspect that you are using JDK 1.6 or before to compile

Comment: I have updated to 1.8 but get some of the same errors: java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Are you sure that java 1.8 is the one being used? Do `java -version` on the command line. Also how are you building javac/maven/ant/gradle/eclispe?

Comment: @BrainWorx Are you sure you get the _same_ error? And not something about _incompatible types_?

Comment: Sorry, i am so stupid, the class TCPSocket is several pages later. but i think everyone will look for a class included in another class before that class, not several pages later. excuse me, but i have java 1.8 now thats also fine :D